# cant install Java on my windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, java

I am trying to install Java on Windows 10 but I get this annoying error:

[image: Error message]

I've tried many of the YouTube tricks but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what you tried already (those YouTube tricks and any other solution that failed) to avoid getting the same advice that didn't work. See [this troubleshooting article](https://java.com/en/download/help/error_installpackage.xml) as well.

Comment: tried running with administrator privileges, tried running with all permissions by modifying the properties of the temp folder in Appdata folder. Also tried the solutions provided by oracle itself like using their offline installer package and changing proxy settings, nothing works

Comment: What about anti-virus and download managers?

Comment: what about it sir

Comment: Anti-virus and download managers are two other things the Oracle article suggests you should check.

Comment: tried those too sir

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to install Java, so I tried installing an IDE which included Java. Here are a few:

- [IntelliJ Portable](https://github.com/portapps/intellij-idea-community-portable)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html#_downloading)

Add the `jre\bin` folder to the PATH environment variable [for your account](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/113/windows-10-set-path.html) and try running `java` in Powershell and it should work.

[Sideloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideloading) a zipped installation from another Windows machine would work as well.